# Grails searchable plugin query

Tags: grails, lucene, searchable

I'm using the searchable plug-in in my grails project,

I have a domain class like this:

```
class Item {
...
String dominantColor
String palette
...

static searchable = {
     ....
    only: ['title', 'description' ,'palette' , 'dominantColor']
}
```

**dominantColor** is a String containing a color name like  :

> Green

**palette**  is a String containing a list of colors name like this  :

> ["Desert sand","Dark jungle green","Outer Space","Dim gray","Slate
>   gray","Army green","Dark electric blue","Cadet grey","Dark chestnut"]

and I'm trying to search only items with selected color, I tried like this:

```
def searchResult = Item.search({
    must(term("Item.publication", true))
    must(term("Item.Itemlist.isPublished", true))
    must{queryString(query)}
    if(params.color){
        String selectedColor = params.selectedColorName
        must{
            term('Item.dominantColor', selectedColor)
            term('Item.palette', selectedColor)
            }
        }
}).results
```

But doesn't work, can anyone help me figuring out what is wrong with my query?

**Edit** 
I noticed that

```
 must{term('proprityName ', value)
```

doesn't work with String value,

when i tried with only this , it work

```
  must(term("Item.publication", true))
```

but  with this it didn't

```
  term('Item.dominantColor', "Green")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that your values input into the index are being analyzed, and are all lowercased.

When you construct your queries though, there is no analysis happening, so they won't be automatically lowercased.  Try:

```
term('Item.dominantColor', "green")
```

Comment: thx femtoRgon :D , it was that ,now do you know how to search words with space , for exemple if i want to search "dark gray"  ==> term('Item.dominantColor', "dark gray") doesn't work

Comment: I work around this problem by adding a concatenation before inserting color into the database, then i search like this term('Item.dominantColor', "darkgray") but I think this is not the best nor the cleanest method :p

Comment: There you need to handle it as a phrase, so you could use something like either: `querystring:"\"dark gray\""`, or use `multiPhrase`, which you can see an example of in the [Documentation of Query Builder](http://grails.org/Searchable+Plugin+-+Searching+-+Query+Builder)